# Why does VBA Workbook.Close Statement Fail Inside Workbook_BeforeClose, If Close is Triggered Programmatically?

Tags: excel, vba, events, event-driven

i'd like to intercept BeforeClose with my own process, and cancel the default process. Not working as expected. To replicate, create a new workbook, enter the following, and save:

ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
          Cancel = True
          Application.EnableEvents = False  ' to prevent recursively calling this procedure
          ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

On the Excel front-end, close the workbook manually by clicking the close-X. It will close, as expected, by the ThisWorkbook.Close statement. In Excel 2016 and 365, if other workbooks are open, they remain open.

Beware, EnableEvents will now be false. Close and reopen Excel to restore it, or enter in immediate pane:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Now reopen the same workbook. Put a breakpoint on Workbook_BeforeClose. Go to front end and again manually close the workbook. Step through the code, to confirm what it's doing. Still works fine.

Restore EnableEvents as described above.

Open the file once more. Go to immediate pane, and enter:
ThisWorkbook.Close

The file will *not* close. Step through the code to see what's happening. Still doesn't close. Why not?

Comment: Trying to reproduce the process, and this is what I get. For the last step, events are **true**, as I run .close the workbook indeed doesn't close, but the events are set to **false**. On next try, the workbook closes normally.

Comment: As far as I can tell – ThisWorkbook.Close can't call ThisWorkbook.Close. Maybe to prevent  some kind of infinite loop. Closing the book will trigger the event, and will call any ThisWorkbook.Close, but only **ONCE**. When closing with ThisWorkbook.Close this won't happen, since it's already called.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber "ThisWorkbook.Close can't call ThisWorkbook.Close" - Is one of those supposed to be `Workbook_BeforeClose`?

Comment: Not really. `ThisWorkbook.Close` will call `Workbook_BeforeClose`. But only once, hence ignoring any `ThisWorkbook.Close`, as per my answer. `Workbook_BeforeClose` can call `ThisWorkbook.Close` unless that is the thing calling `Workbook_BeforeClose`. Sorry if I'm using "Calling" the wrong way.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber "some kind of infinite loop." - If you set EnableEvents = False, as in my question, then you can't get an infinite loop.

Comment: My point is, even if you don't, you don't get an infinite loop.

Comment: I followed your steps, and cofirm your results.  Observation: if I execture `ThisWorkbook.Close` from the immediate window a _second_ time, it _does_ close

Comment: On that second attempt, EnableEvents is false, so the Event is not triggered.

Comment: Observation 2: When you do get the WB to close from the imediate window, the Excel Appilcation remains running, which is different to closing from the UI.  May be a clue

Comment: Observation 3: no mattter how many time you issue `ThisWorkbook.Close` _from the immediate window_ and with `EnableEvent = true`, it won't close

Comment: All that said, and _I_ see no ready explanation for the behaviour, but I wonder: what's your use case that this creates a problem for?

Comment: Observation 4: creating a `Sub` that (only) calls `ThisWorkbook.Close` exibits the same behaviour as calling it from the immediate window (this may answer the use case Q)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Obs 4: Can that Sub be called by the `_BeforeClose` event?

Comment: it makes sense that a .Close statement will work if events are disables, since the _BeforeClose won't run in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
          MsgBox "Start"
          ThisWorkbook.Close
          ThisWorkbook.Close
          MsgBox "End"
End Sub
```

This seems to confirm my comment.
If `ThisWorkbook.Close` could call `ThisWorkbook.Close`, this would indefinitely spam "Start" message boxes.

Closing the book normally gives you **two** "start" and **one** "end"

- So it goes back to the start of `BeforeClose` on `ThisWorkbook.Close` the first time, then ignores it.

Closing it with `ThisWorkbook.Close` gives **one** "start and **one** "end"

- Because it ignores both `ThisWorkbook.Close`

### But

in this case, starting with `ThisWorkbook.Close` should have them always behave the same. And this **isn't** the case.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Close

    ThisWorkbook.Close

    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False  ' to prevent recursively calling this procedure

    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Take a look how this code executes when closed with `ThisWorkbook.Close`:
[image]
It doesn't close

And then from the menu:
[image]
It closes

If we don't disable the events, running it from `ThisWorkbook.Close`behaves exactly the same. Steps through, doesn't close.
From the menu however, it's quite different:
[image]
And doesn't close.

So it seems that calling `Workbook_BeforeClose`using `ThisWorkbook.Close` will ignore all other `ThisWorkbook.Close`, but closing the document with the menu will try to run each `ThisWorkbook.Close` **once**.

Comment: i'm unclear if your code is meant to demonstrate that a workaround is possible, or not possible? It's unclear to me why you have `ThisWorkbook.Close` inside the `Workbook_BeforeClose` procedure. Since you haven't set Cancel to True, the book will close even without your `ThisWorkbook.Close`.

Comment: It's to demonstrate how `ThisWorkbook.Close` behaves differently inside of the `Workbook_BeforeClose` when called by closing the document vs using `ThisWorkbook.Close`. But yes, it will close either way, this is to understand how it works, not a workaround.

Comment: I'm unclear what this demonstrates, if You're not setting EnableEvents to false, as in my question.

Comment: This demonstrates the answer to your question: "Why does VBA Workbook.Close Statement Fail Inside Workbook_BeforeClose, If Close is Triggered Programmatically?" The answer being: If `Workbook_BeforeClose` is initiated by `ThisWorkbook.Close`, any other `ThisWorkbook.Close` will be ignored. `EnableEvents` doesn't change this, so it's not relevant for the answer.

Comment: Great insight! Now to find a way to cancel the first .Close, while not disabling a subsequent .Close

Comment: i question your assertion "If ThisWorkbook.Close could call ThisWorkbook.Close, this would indefinitely spam "Start" message boxes." -- Not if you set EnableEvents to False, i think. if i'm right about that, then the infinite loop can be avoided. Therefor, that wouldn't be the reason subsequent .Close's are ignored. If VBA was trying to prevent infinite loops, then recursion wouldn't be supported (which it is).

Comment: It seems you're validating the behavior that my question already describes -- the subsequent `.Close` is ignored -- while not explaining why. It seems inconsistent for VBA to disallow sequential `.Close`'s, but allow a `.Close` after a front-end manual close.

Comment: Actually, it seems like I was wrong, and it's even stranger. Because if what I said was true, a `.close` at the start of `_BeforeClose` would have them behave in the same way. But in your example, they still don't. I'll add another funky experiment.

Answer (score 1):

*On the Excel front-end, close the workbook manually. It will close, as expected, by the ThisWorkbook.Close statement.*

well, not quite:

If you close from the UI by clicking the Top Right `X`, the the described behviour *dose* occur.  On the other hand, if you close from the UI by going to File/Close then the behaviour mirrors the immediate window beviour described (doesn't close)

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforeclose)

> Cancel Required    Boolean

> False when the event occurs. If the event procedure sets this argument to True, **the close operation stops and the workbook is left open.**

This explains the observed behaviour.

If you set `cancel = True` just before `ThisWorkbook.Close` then it does close.

So, why does clicking the `X` close it?

I believe it's because that UI is also exiting the Excel Application.  The workbook close as a side effect of the Application Quitting, as do *all* open workbooks.

Comment: In Excel 2016 and 365, if you have other workbooks open, clicking the close-X closes only one workbook -- other workbooks remain open.